# Getting an Error while Creating a iPhone Archive application

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcodebuild

When I try to build and Archive. I get the following warning due to the which the archive is never created. I have re-created the certificates and Distributon profiles, couple of times but without any success. I'm using Xcode 4.2.1 on Lion

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/harjitsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pixTraining-esipiqauyjdzovexgfzrwtdvxblk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/pixTraining.app/pixTraining
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, U4VTF92U2W.PiX
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers, <CFArray 0x10790a920 [0x7fff76712fc0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x10790a950 [0x7fff76712fc0]>{contents = "U4VTF92U2W.PiX"}
)}
AssertMacros: filter_entitlements(entitlements_whitelist, entitlements_requested, allowable_entitlements),  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 932
 - (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the project and the name of the Archive didn't match and hence the error. I Was using #appcelerator to code my App. Hope this helps